# Line endings cohabiting Terminal and Eclipse Git

Tags: eclipse, git, terminal, line-endings

We are corking on a project and managing our code versions with Git. We have one branch per feature, one branch per version we are maintaining... The problem is, we connected the project to git using command line (Eclipse doesn't provide enough features to do that correctly) but generally we use Eclipse to commit, push... 
In addition sometimes Eclipse didn't want to let us push, and we were forced to push in command line.

This situation resulted with some files on remote being on crlf line endings and some other with lf line endings. All that caused by Eclipse and terminal acting differently with libne endings, and I realised that too late. I am now searching for a simple, proper way to make all files auto crlf at true and a procedure that guaranty the same behavior on Terminal and Eclipse on all git clients (basing behavior on terminal).

(sorry for bad English and thanks by advance ) !

--EDIT--

I should have precised I am searching for a solution that would work for converting existing files too, converting remote files into lf on remote and crlf on the repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding and committing a `.gitattributes` file in the repository with this entry.

```
* text eol=crlf
```

(Reference:
https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

> Git will always convert line endings to CRLF on checkout. You should
>   use this for files that must keep CRLF endings, even on OSX or Linux.

**Illustration:**

Consider there are 2 files in existing repo (say `test-repo`) with one line in each.

```
file_a.txt
file_b.txt
```

Verify file endings as `\n`.

```
test-repo (master)$ od -c file_a.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       f   i   l   e   _   a  \n
0000017

test-repo (master)$ od -c file_b.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       f   i   l   e   _   b  \n
0000017
```

Add a `.gitattributes` file in repository.

```
test-repo (master)$ vim .gitattributes
```

Add entry.

```
* text eol=crlf
```

Commit and push `.gitattributes`.

```
test-repo (master)$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitattributes.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

test-repo (master)$ git commit -m "Adding .gitattributes file"

test-repo (master)$ git push
```

Add a new file, and type a line of text in it.

```
test-repo (master)$ vim file_c.txt
```

Verify file ending as `\n`.

```
test-repo (master)$ od -c file_c.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       f   i   l   e   _   c  \n
0000017
```

Commit and push the added file.

```
test-repo (master)$ git add file_c.txt
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file_c.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

test-repo (master)$ git commit -m "Added file_c.txt"

test-repo (master)$ git push
```

Clone the repository to another directory on disk (say with the name `temp_dir`). Note the endings are now `\r \n` in lieu of `\n`.

```
temp_dir/test-repo (master) $ od -c file_a.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       f   i   l   e   _   a  \r  \n
0000020

temp_dir/test-repo (master) $ od -c file_b.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       f   i   l   e   _   b  \r  \n
0000020

temp_dir/test-repo (master) $ od -c file_c.txt
0000000    T   h   i   s       i   s       f   i   l   e   _   c  \r  \n
0000020
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, your solution work with new files, I was actually searching for a solution for the existing files on the remote, something that wouls convert all files on remote into lf, all files on repository on crlf and keep terminal behavior for future files (I Should have been more clear about that sorry)

Comment: @AmaniteLaurine: it works with existing files too. Remember, *nothing committed can ever be changed* so no files that are in any *commit* change. However, it's important to keep in mind the distinction Git makes between (1) committed files, (2) proposed-commit files in the index/staging-area, and (3) files in the work-tree. The `eol=crlf` setting affects *files in the work-tree*, and that includes *existing* files extracted from commits, when they move from commit to index/staging-area and then on to the work-tree.

Comment: Git has several control options for dealing with files that are already committed in the wrong format, including `merge.renormalize`. The stored version in an existing commit does not change, but Git makes a new "virtual commit" by extracting and re-committing before doing the merge operation. There is a time penalty for this but it gets around the read-only nature of existing commits.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I figured out tht eclipse was not supporting gitattributes here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372 
The status of the bug is still "assigned", I suppose it is not fixed yet but is there another way to make Eclipse support gitattributes ?